# Error in Post Requst (Kusto & Databricks)

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to follow the example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/spark-connector):

Here is my code:

```
import com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.KustoOptions
import com.microsoft.kusto.spark.sql.extension.SparkExtension._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val cluster = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "key-vault-secrets", key = "ClusterName")
val client_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "key-vault-secrets", key = "ClientId")
val client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "key-vault-secrets", key = "ClientSecret")
val authority_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "key-vault-secrets", key = "TenantId")
val database = "db"
val table = "tablename"

val conf: Map[String, String] = Map(
      KustoOptions.KUSTO_AAD_CLIENT_ID -> client_id,
      KustoOptions.KUSTO_AAD_CLIENT_PASSWORD -> client_secret,
      KustoOptions.KUSTO_QUERY -> s"$table | top 100"      
    )

// Simplified syntax flavor
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.microsoft.kusto.spark.sql.extension.SparkExtension._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val df = spark.read.kusto(cluster, database, "", conf)
display(df)
```

However this gives me this error:

```
com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.exceptions.DataServiceException: Error in post request
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.Utils.post(Utils.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.execute(ClientImpl.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.execute(ClientImpl.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.kusto.spark.utils.KustoDataSourceUtils$.getSchema(KustoDataSourceUtils.scala:103)
    at com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.KustoRelation.getSchema(KustoRelation.scala:102)
    at com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.KustoRelation.schema(KustoRelation.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:450)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:201)
    at com.microsoft.kusto.spark.sql.extension.SparkExtension$DataFrameReaderExtension.kusto(SparkExtension.scala:19)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:25)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:86)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:88)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:90)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:92)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1810687702746193:94)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read.<init>(command-1810687702746193:96)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$.<init>(command-1810687702746193:100)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$read$.<clinit>(command-1810687702746193)
    at linef172a4a7eaa6435fa4ff9fec071cf03535.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like you forgot to use the 'table' val in the reading command, so you initiated an empty query. Also you didn't provide here the full exception (might need to scroll down or look in driver logs)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the format of your cluster name matches the expected format.

The expected is `clustername.region`

Answer (score 0):

In the file you are reading your query from, make sure you append a line break ( `\n` ) at the end of each line.